# Is $\hat t$ orthogonal to the tangent space of the spatial hypersurface?

Tags: general-relativity

For a 3-D manifold ($r,\theta,\phi$) and sub-manifold (2-sphere)($\theta,\phi$) , $\hat r$ is orthogonal to both the 2-sphere and tangent space associated with each point of the 2-sphere.
Similarly for 4-D manifold($r,\theta,\phi,t$) ,and sub-manifold(hypersurface)($r,\theta,\phi$) if $\hat t$ is orthogonal to the hypersurface(space like) for which the metric becomes $$ds^2=g(t)dt^2+f(t)\delta_{ij}\gamma_{ij}dx^idx^j$$(no cross terms between  $t$ and $x^{is}$)where $x^i$ are the spatial coordinates ,is it necessary that $\hat t$ is also orthogonal to the tangent space associated with each point of the hypersurface??

Answer (score 0):

The components of the metric tensor are defined as $g_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \cdot \partial_\nu$, where $\cdot$ is the scalar product and $\partial_\mu$ is a coordinate basis vector.

If a metric has no off-diagonal terms, the coordinate basis vectors are othogonal to each other.

Comment: Yes it is but my question is if $\hat t$ is orthogonal to spatial hypersurface ,then whether $\hat t$ will also be orthogonal to tangent space associated with each point of the spatial hypersurface??

Comment: The tangent space to each point of the spacelike hypersurface is made up of the coordinate bases associated to the coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$. A vector, in this case $\hat t$, is orthogonal to a hypersurface, if it is orthogonal to the tangent space of the hypersurface. It is a definition.